# WPF,C#: Space in Menu command

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, contextmenu

I have a WPF menu I am using, and it simply doesn't like when I have a space in the Command.

```
<MenuItem Command="Add to Catalog">
</MenuItem>
```

It always throws a nasty error when creating the view, and Visual Studio complains

```
Cannot resolve symbol "Add to Catalog".
```

If I have a single piece of text with no whitespace, it works fine.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I have seen other example. It's look like

Comment: <MenuItem Name="menuItem_Close" Header="Close"
          Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.CloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding `Command` to some method. `C#` doesn't allow to use spaces in method's or variable names. So why should `XAML` allow you to use spaces when your method name look like 'AddtoCatalog' or 'Add_to_Catalog'? You just binding it to non-existing method.

Probably you want to set Header name for menu item? There you can have spaces. Here is example:

```
<MenuItem Header="Add to Catalog" Command="{Binding Add_to_Catalog}"/>
```

*where Add_to_Catalog is your method name.

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to bind the command to a CommandBinding, something like this.

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="AddToCatalog" CanExecute="AddToCatalog_CanExecute" Executed="AddToCatalog_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Now you can easily use the command as such

```
<MenuItem Command="AddToCatalog" Header="Add to Catalog">
</MenuItem>
```

Notice that the header is different. That is the text that is visible in the menu.